# Dynamic Table Using Procedure Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-queries

I have 2 procedures p1 and p2 each giving results in format as below

```
exec p1----> #col1 #col2
              P-1   52
              P-2   25

EXEC p2----> #col1 #col2
              P-1   20
              P-2   2
              P-3   5
```

I want to call these procedure in another procedure which will execute the two procedure ,create a temp table and insert the result of the two table as shown below:

```
#col1 #col2 #col3
P-1    52    20
P-2    25    2
P-3    NULL  5
```

I am new to using Temp table any help would be appreciated.
This code has to be run in SQL server.
Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Comment: Hi I tried that but is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want .Try once it may help you

As per your procedures output follow below query

```
create table #tempp (col1 varchar(50),col2 bigint)

insert into #temp
exec p1

create table #tempp1 (col1 varchar(50),col2 bigint)

insert into #tempp1
exec p2

select t1.col1,t.col2,t1.col2 from #tempp t
full join #tempp1 t1 on t.col1=t1.col1
```

I have created sample data as like your procedure output data and tried in my db

```
              select * into #tempp from (
              select 'p-1' as col1,52 col2
              union all
              select 'p-2',25
              ) as a

              select * into #tempp1 from (
              select 'p-1' as col1,20 col2
              union all
              select 'p-2',2
                union all
              select 'p-3',5
              ) as a

select t1.col1,t.col2,t1.col2 from #tempp t
full join #tempp1 t1 on t.col1=t1.col1
```

Your output looks like

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col2 |
+------+------+------+
| p-1  | 52   |   20 |
| p-2  | 25   |    2 |
| p-3  | NULL |    5 |
+------+------+------+
```